# problem while validation text field after 

Tags: iphone

i need to validate a textfield input that allows two digits after a `.`.
Eg: if i enter 2.333 it wont allow if can able to allow 2.33 only.

for that i use this code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSArray *sep = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count]==2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]=2);
    }
}
```

if i use `return !([sepStr length]=2)` it works fine that wont allow to enter next value.

But if i remove value also text field wont allow any modifications.
i mean there is no user interaction.
It can't able to edit.
can any one please help me.
How can i correct this.
Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code by Thomas Clayson is that the user still can't edit the text field anymore when he types for example: "1234" and after that inserts a "." between 1 and 2, or if he pastes a number in the textfield.

Here's a better solution:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count]>=2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that you aren't evaluating the return. You have a single `=` and that is setting the value rather than evaluating the expression. This will always cause the function to return false in your case.

Here is my edit anyway:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSArray *sep = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count]==2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1],replacementString];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
}
```

All I've changed was to add `(NSString *)string` onto the current text value of the textField and then tested to see if it was **more** than 2 characters.

Comment: Thank u Thoma clayson,You save my valuable time,This works fine.Very Quick Response Great